# Setup Subdomain Apach2 Ubuntu 10.04. Virtual Host not in use currently

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, virtualhost, subdomain, website

I have a ubuntu 10.04 server that is currently setup only to run a single website. I would like to setup a subdomain to point to specific section of this website. For example, I want test.example.com to point to example.com/testing. What is the best way to make this happen?

Comment: Can you clarify what behavior you're looking to achieve?  "point to" is vague; are you looking to redirect, serve the content from the subdomain transparently, or something else? And can you provide more information about your current configuration?  Ubuntu's default configuration uses virtual hosts - have you removed those?

Comment: I want to have test.example.com load the webpage at /var/www/test. Where as example.com typically just loads /var/www. I installed apache2 and made no modifications to it. So however it is by default is how I have it set up currently.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new vhost:

```
touch /etc/apache2/sites-available/test.example.com
```

Give it some content:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test
    # ..any other config needed
    <Directory /var/www/test>
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Enable it:

```
a2ensite test.example.com
```

And restart Apache:

```
service apache2 restart
```

Make sure name resolution for the new `test.example.com` name is pointing to your server correctly.